# how to pass array to a session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem in storing an array in a session of codeigniter. here is my code

the new_results session seems not to work

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('search' => $q));
$search = $this->session->userdata('search');
$current = $this->session->userdata('q');
$new_results= $this->session->userdata('new_results');
if($search==$current)
{
    $new_results = $this->session->userdata('new_results');
    print_r($new_results);
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_userdata(array("q" => $search));
    $start = 0;
    $results = array();
    $query = $q . " (site:vodlocker.com OR site:vidbull.com OR site:putlocker.com/embed OR site:putlocker.com/file OR site:sockshare.com/file OR site:sockshare.com/embed)";
    while($start<=100){
        $snoopy = new Snoopy;

        $googleurl = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode(trim($query))."&start=".$start;

        $snoopy->fetchlinks($googleurl);
        $result = $snoopy->results;
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            if(!in_array($row, $results))
                $results[] = $row;
        }
        $start+=10;
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata(array("new_results" => $results));
    $new_results = $this->session->userdata("new_results");
    print_r($this->session->userdata("new_results"));

}
```

Comment: what driver you are using? store session in database

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata("q", $search); should do

Comment: @Saqueib . sorry for the incomplete info. i have updated my post

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: see whats $this->session->all_userdata() giving you

Comment: @Saqueib i have tried it. on the else part. the array will be printed. but in the if part, it the session mysteriously changed

Comment: plz check you haven't overwritten new_results key above if condition.

Comment: @Saqueib . because in the if part . im planning to get the new_result session. after going to the else part. i will refresh the web and it will go to if part but when i print all the session. the new_result session is not there.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$newdata = array(
               'username'  => 'johndoe',
               'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );
  $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

For more information please visit this link:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html